# Animation out of sync, how to achieve smooth animation?

Tags: javascript, css

Image and backgroung color out of sync. And i need smooth animation so the image & bgcolor fade's together.
It works smooth only on first iteration. Check codepen, please. I spent 5 hours and did not understand what was happening. It works smooth only on first iteration. Check codepen, please. I spent 5 hours and did not understand what was happening. 
https://codepen.io/l-ba-iwanowa/pen/poJZQVN

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>

body,
 .col-1,
 .col-3-4,
  .col-1 p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 15px  50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-name: bbb;
  animation-duration: 5s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

#rcorners1:hover {
 width:600px;
  transform: translate(300px); 
  transition:1s;
}

@keyframes bbb {
 0% {background-color: blue;}
 100% {background-color: red}
}


.asd {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.asd img{
 width: 100%;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
}

.asd img {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
}

.asd img.top {
 /*position:relative;*/
 
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 2s;

}
/*
.asd img.top:hover  {
 opacity: 100;
}*/


.trans {
 opacity: 100  !important;
}


#container {
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.col-1 {
 width:25%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.col-3-4 {
 width:75%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.relative {
 position:relative;
}


.black-col {
 position: relative;
 top: -150px;
 background: #474747;
 height: 300px;
 color:white;
 padding: 1rem;
}

.zastup {
 position: relative;
 top:-50px;
 background-color: white;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.slider-bg {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 transition: background-color 2s;
}



#container2 {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}





.slider-nav {
 float:right !important;
}




ul {
 /* Center the content */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    /* Reset styles */
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {

 /* Rounded border */
        border-radius: 9999px;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;

        /* Active dot */
        /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);*/

        /* Inactive dot */
         background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
        /*border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);*/

        /* OPTIONAL: Spacing between dots */
        margin: 0 12px;
        transition: transform 0.5s, background-color 0.5s;
}

.nav-active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  transform: scale(1.5);

}

.clear {
 clear:both;
 zoom: 1;
}



.col-1-3 {
 position: relative;
 width: 33%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 1rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.abc {
 border: 0;
 background-color: #e86d10;
 padding: 1rem 2rem;
border-radius: 25px;
font-size: inherit;
color: #fff;

}


.price {
 font-size:1.5rem;
 position: relative;
 top:-20px;
}

.description {
 position: relative;
 top:-40px;
word-break: break-all;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-size: 1.2rem;
 
 }

.p1rem {
 padding: 1rem;
}

.orange {
 color: #e86d10;
}

.apply-font {
 font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;

}


.bg-black {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}


.bg-blue {
 background-color: rgb(34, 73, 200);
}


 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="container">


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur illum ab corrupti impedit culpa provident nemo numquam? Magnam, rerum, magni. Autem quisquam deserunt a est iste iure odit laudantium, dolores.</p>

</div>

<div class="slider-bg ">
<div class="asd">

 <!-- <img  src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tAp9BKosZXs/maxresdefault.jpg" alt=""> -->
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xCGxXuy.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://i.imgur.com/D1tDvcG.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gBv91a9YqyhIxGsxc26x5TORV_8=/0x0:1296x730/1200x800/filters:focal(669x161:875x367)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/66274455/horsegirl.0.jpg" alt="">
 <img  class="top" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-73o9cfxSC7Q/XQMxoVjfdMI/AAAAAAAAUkM/RSi0lSlsQoAfhMHLR-3U8Sfk_PpvZuziQCLcBGAs/s1600/copertina.jpg" alt="">



</div></div>

<div id="container2" style="position: relative;top:-60px; ">
 <ul class="slider-nav">
   <li data-id='0' class="nav-active"></li>
   <li data-id='1'></li>
   <li data-id='2'></li>
   <li data-id='3'></li>
   <li data-id='4'></li>
  </ul></div><div class="clear"></div>

<div id="container2">
 <div class="col-1 black-col">asd</div><!-- 
  --><div class="col-3-4 zastup">







<!-- <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.1.0/anime.min.js'></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(111);
// document.querySelector('#btn-click').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
//  document.querySelector('.top').classList.toggle("trans");
//  console.log(document.querySelector('.top').classList);
// });


let p = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-bg img');
let pp = Array.from(p);
console.log(pp);

function changeBgColor (){


 if (i == 0 ) {

  document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
 }
  if (i == 1 ) {
   document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(34, 73, 200)';
 }
  if (i == 2 ) {document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'red';}
  if (i == 3 ) {document.querySelector('.slider-bg').style.backgroundColor = 'green';}

}

let i = 1;
function asd(arguments) {
 setTimeout(()=>{
 // b = arrayImages[i];
 // document.querySelector('#slider-hero img').src = b;

  let z = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let zz = Array.from(z);
  zz.forEach((item)=>{item.classList.remove('nav-active')});
  // console.log(el);
  zz[i].classList.add('nav-active');

  

 b = pp[i];
 pp.forEach((val)=>{
  val.classList.remove('trans');
  
 });
 b.classList.add('top');
 b.classList.add('trans');
 changeBgColor();
 i++;
 if (i ==4) {
  i =0;
 }

 console.log(b);
 asd();
},4000);
}
asd();

document.querySelector('.slider-nav').addEventListener('click',(el)=>{
 if (el.target.tagName === 'LI') {
  let z = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let zz = Array.from(z);
  console.log(el.target.dataset.id);
   b = pp[el.target.dataset.id];
   pp.forEach((val)=>{
    val.classList.remove('trans');
    
   });
   b.classList.add('top');
   b.classList.add('trans'); 


  zz.forEach((item)=>{item.classList.remove('nav-active');});
   
  el.target.classList.add('nav-active');

  i = el.target.dataset.id;
  changeBgColor();
 }

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like it's working fine - what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, everything works. But after the first iteration, the transition is not smooth. You see, the edges of the picture are visible square at the transition, but it should be smooth as a gradient.

Comment: no, everything is smooth all the time for me in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems working fine to Chrome Browser. You can validate the css for all the browser using: https://www.browseemall.com/Compatibility/ValidateCSS

There might be chances of browser compatibility issues.

Seems broken in IE10 and lower.

```
ul{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:center;list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
```